# how to return multiple anchor by format_html in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

what currently i have is :

```py
def Action(self, obj):
        return format_html(
            '<a class="button" title="View" href="view/{}"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;'
            '<a class="button delete_vehicle trash-icon" title="Delete" data-id="{}" href="delete/{}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',
            (obj.id),
            (obj.id),
            (obj.id),
```

But i am trying to pass three html it not retuning me the third anchor ..

```py
return format_html(
                '<a class="button" title="View" href="view/{}"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>&nbsp;'
                '<a class="button delete_vehicle trash-icon" title="Delete" data-id="{}" href="delete/{}"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',

'<a class="button edit" title="edit" data-id="{}" href="edit/{}"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>',

                (obj.id),
                (obj.id),
                (obj.id),
(obj.id),
```

why i am not getting this can anyone please help me in related this.how can i pass or return three anchor.

Comment: any help related to this ???

Answer (score 1):

```
I have found the solution
 view = '<a href="%s">1</a>' % (obj.id)
        view2 = '<a href="%s">2</a>' % (obj.id)
        view3 = '<a href="%s">3</a>' % (obj.id)
        return format_html(view + view2+ view3)
```